# I'm getting a Cannot read property value error in this login script: Any ideas? Here is the whole html in a text format:

Tags: javascript, html

Error type: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

```
login.php:20 Uncaught TypeError: 
    at validaremail (login.php:20)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (login.php:73)
validaremail @ login.php:20
onchange @ login.php:73
```

https://codepen.io/nelsonrita11/project/editor/ANaQKO

pls help me.

Comment: It would help to see the code that is generating the error

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow require to be answerable without visiting any external links. Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] as text into your question. You can create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you want to make it runnable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your script runs before the HTML markup is loaded. You are trying to select the `id="email"` element before it appears in the DOM, so it's `null`, so `email.value` is undefined.

Run your script at the end of the `<body>`, after all the HTML markup.

Comment: If this is the case, then it is [a very common duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element). No need for yet another answer.

Comment: @JeremyThille Don't assume who downvoted you. I _did_ vote to close because the question is lacking the necessary details in the question itself. I'm just saying that if this question is indeed the answer, it adds no value over the already existing duplicate. A downvote ("This answer is not useful") is not that odd in this scenario.